# use regex as keywords in ruby hash

Tags: ruby, regex, hash

I have hash mapping

```
H = {
    "alc" => "AL",
    "alco" => "AL",
    "alcoh" => "AL",
    "alcohol" => "AL",
    "alcoholic" => "AL",
}
```

now I want to use a regex to represent all the keys, like
    H={
        /^alc/ => "AL"
    }

later on I want to use H["alc"] or H["alco"] to retrieve the value. But if I use regex, I can not get the value properly. What should I do?

Comment: You want to use the keys in a hash to dynamically build a regex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a subclass, inherit `Hash` class and override `[]` behaviour so it checks whether it matches each regex in your hash and returns the corresponding value.

Comment: Better override [] on the instance only, no need for a subclass.

Comment: Unless he wishes to have more than one instance with the overridden method.

Answer (score 6):

```
class MyHash < Hash
  def [](a)
    self.select {|k| k =~ a}.shift[1]
  end
end

result = MyHash.new

result[/^alc/] = "AL"

puts result['alcohol'] #=> 'AL'
```

I would create a subclass of the hash and then over write this method. This way you can still keep the regular hash functionality elsewhere.

Comment: While I was coding you posted your answer. I only saw your answer once I posted this... There are also many different ways of coding the same thing. Would your implementation be different ?

Comment: Probably a little, but would keep the same concept. Something like `self.each{|key, value| return value if exp=~key}`.